# javascript is will not run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a simple vote/poll program with javascript, I have tried to run it on xammp to see if it needed to be executed on a web server with no success. Do I need to include any script js files apart from vote.js like jquery or something? I am not sure.

Can someone help Thanks.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Vote</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="vote.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="content">
    <h3 class="title">Who's better ?</h3>
<ul>
    <li class="option" id="option_1">
        Messi

        <p class="score" id="score_1">0</p>

        <div class="progressbar">
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="option" id="option_2">
        Ronaldo

        <p class="score" id="score_2">0</p>

        <div class="progressbar">
        </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.content {
background-color: #5C5C5C;
height: 500px;
width: 600px;
font-family: CorpidRegular,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
color: #fff;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.progressbar_1 {
width: 400px;
border-radius: 0px;
margin-left: 100px;
}
.progressbar_2 {
width: 400px;
border-radius: 0px;
margin-left: 100px;
}

h3{    
text-align: center;
padding: 40px;
margin: 0px;
font-weight: normal;
}
ul{
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
padding: 0px;
}
.option:first-child {
background: blue;
}
.option {
background: black;
}
li{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover {
color: yellow;
}
```

js

```
var totalVotes = 0;

$('.option').click(function() {
var $this = $(this);

// store voting value in data-voting
if (!$this.data('voting'))
    $this.data('voting', 0);

var voting = parseInt($this.data('voting'), 10);
voting++;
totalVotes++;

$this.data('voting', voting);

updateProgressBars();
});

function updateProgressBars()
{
$('.option').each(function()
    {
    var $this = $(this);
    var voting = parseInt($(this).data('voting'), 10);
    var pct = Math.round((voting / totalVotes) * 100);

    if (isNaN(voting)) voting = 0;
    if (isNaN(pct)) pct = 0;

    $this.find('progressbar').progressbar({value: pct});
    $this.find('.score').html(voting + ' of ' + totalVotes + ' (' + pct + '%)');
    });
}
```

Comment: Since you are using jQuery library functions, you do need to include the jQuery script in your page and it needs to be included before `vote.js` is included.

Comment: Thanks, I've just included the latest jquery from the site. This is how i've implemented it["<script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>"]. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Always look in your browser error console or debug console for script errors.

Comment: I see $this.data('voting') in you jQuery code but I do not see 'voting' as data attribute anywhere in yout HTML code.

Comment: @Ashish `.data` access jQuery's internal storage *and* data-* attributes. You can see in `$this.data('voting', 0);` zero is stored into `voting`.

Answer (score -2):

You only close html tag, didin't open  tag